# To be a Class based view or a generic class base view?

Tags: django, django-class-based-views

So below I have just created by first Class based view after watching a Django Con EU talk video.

It works and understand what it does. **I don't understand the difference between a Class based view or a generic class base view - which I have just build?**

```
class GroupListView(ListView):
    """
    List all Groups.
    """
    context_object_name = 'groups'
    template_name = 'contacts/home.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        """
        Get the context for this view.
        """
        # Call the base implementation first to get a context.
        context = super(GroupListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        # Add more contexts.
        context['tasks'] = Upload.objects.filter(uploaded_by=self.request.user).order_by('-date_uploaded')[:5]
        context['unsorted'] = Contact.objects.unsorted_contacts(user=self.request.user).count()

        return context

    def get_queryset(self):
        """
        Get the list of items for this view. This must be an iterable, and may
        be a queryset (in which qs-specific behavior will be enabled).
        """
        queryset = Group.objects.for_user(self.request.user)
        return queryset
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Django comes with a set of views that are trying to solve some common problems, eg:

- Editing an object
- Displaying a single object
- Displaying a list of objects

Because these views can be used for different models, they are called **generic**.
"Generic" in this case hasn't anything to do with the way they are implemented - in older Django version function views were the default (the views were functions), now they have became classes.

Your example view is actually a *class-based view* that inherits from a *class-based generic view*.

Comment: I see, this is where my confusion is coming from. So if I was just using a generic view I don't see how I would add any more  functionally like in my get_context_data super etc. So what your saying is I could just just a class view without the inheritance of a generic class? Any reason why not to do this?

Comment: If you need any functionality that is already provided by a generic view you'll most probably try to use this and maybe modify it. If you want to create your "own" view from scratch inherit from `django.views.generic.base.View` (guess it is a bit confusing that it lives in `views.generic`).  [This](http://ccbv.co.uk/) is a good starting point if you would like to browse through the views...

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/class-based-views/intro/#using-class-based-views

Answer (score 3):

A [Class based view](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/class-based-views/intro/) is *any* Django view provided as a Python Class (as opposed to views as functions).

A [Generic base View](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/class-based-views/base/) in Django is the base for any of the built-in views which you can use for your convenience. Examples:

- ListView
- CreateView
- DetailView

Those are based on [`django.views.generic.base.View`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/class-based-views/base/#django.views.generic.base.View).

Answer (score 1):

`ListView` is a generic class-based view (which means, it comes with Django, implements very common features, and is free to be inherited from for more precise handling as you did). On the other hand, `GroupListView` is not generic - as it is not part of Django.

Comment: Django's generic views aren't supposed to be extended, they are also meant to get used the way they are.

Comment: by extended do you mean inherited from @Vincent?

Comment: Yes User7.
And yes Berhard you are right, my sentence was not properly formed.