# Is there any way to combine CreateView and UpdateView?

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I want to show the form present in `CreateView` if there was no item exists inside a model. Else I need to show the form exists in the `UpdateView`. So that it would load the already saved values. Later I should save the data to db by calling [`update_or_create`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#update-or-create) method.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Instead of messing with a double purpose view, which is not trivial to find out which and when to run the correct method (and not recommended), add a third view that will redirect to CreateView or EditView.

It should look something like this:

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

class AddItemView(generic.CreateView):
    ...

class EditItemView(generic.EditView):
    ...

class UpdateItemRedirectView(generic.RedirectView):

   def get_redirect_url(self):

         if Item.objects.get( ...criteria... ).exists():
              return reverse("url_name_of_edit_view")
         else:
              return reverse("url_name_of_add_view")
```

Answer (score 1):

The other "double purpose" view solution that **@AviahLaor** mentions is to combine the `CreateView` and `UpdateView` in one view. In my opinion, it is DRYer. The solution is given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17192737/django-class-based-view-for-both-create-and-update) very well.