# Django CreateUpdateView implementation in the django template

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-class-based-views

I am very new to django [Class based views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/class-based-views/-), trying to integrate it with my existing project.
My goal is to use same `Class based view` to `Create` and `Update` student application form.
I am trying to integrate `CreateUpdateView` from the @scubabuddha's answer from the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17192737/django-class-based-view-for-both-create-and-update).

views.py

```
from createupdateview import CreateUpdateView

class StudentView(CreateUpdateView):
   template_name="admission.html"
   Model = Student
   form_class = StudentForm
  
  def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    return self.post(request, *args, **kwargs)

  def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    forms = {"userform": UserForm(request.POST or None), guardian..., contact..., # other 5-6 forms}
    
    if request.POST:
      invalid_forms = [form.is_valid() for form in self.forms.values()]
      if not all(invalid_forms):
        messages.error(request,'You must fill up all the valid mandatory form fields!')
        return render(request, 'admission.html', forms)
      #-- Logic to validate and save each form
      ...
      return render(request, 'admission.html', forms)  
    return render(request, 'admission.html', forms)
```

This is perfectly working for `CreateView`, but not able to understand how to use this for `UpdateView` or `editview`. If user hits `editview`, `{{form|crispy}}` should also display the details to allow user  to edit the form.

urls.py (I also want to merge below 2 urls to 1, can we do this?)

```
from django.urls import path
from students import views 
from students.views import StudentList, StudentView

urlpatterns = [
    
    path('', StudentList.as_view(), name='students'), 
    path('add/', StudentView.as_view(), name='addview'), 
    path('<int:pk>/edit/', StudentView.as_view(), name='editview'), 
...
]
```

I want to display, all the student details in the `UpdateView` forms -

admission.html

```
<form class="form" name="admissionForm" id="admissionForm" method="post" 
            enctype="multipart/form-data" action="{% url 'addview' %}"> 
 {% csrf_token %}
  <div class="pages">
     <h4 class="mt-2 mb-3">Personal Information</h4>
      {% include "student_errors.html" %}                
      {{userform|crispy}}      #-- It should display student details 
      {{guardian_form|crispy}}    
      {{contact_form|crispy}}    
      ....
      <div class="btn_container">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info float-right btn-next">Submit</button>  
      </div>
 </div>
```

**P.S.**   I kept minimal code here, in actual production its huge code. (Migrating Django applcation 1.9 to 3.0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `CreateUpdateView` you are using from [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17192737/django-class-based-view-for-both-create-and-update) inherits from `ModelFormMixin` and expect to handle only one form (initialization, form_class, saving, ...). And in your code your are rewriting `get()` and `post()` method so it make no sense to inherit from `CreateUpdateView`.

Here is how you can do it using a simple `View` (untested) :

```py
from django.http import Http404
from django.views.generic import View
from django.shortcuts import render

class StudentView(View):
    template_name = "admission.html"

    def get_object(self):
        if self.kwargs.get('pk'):
            try:
                obj = Student.objects.get(pk=pk)
            except Student.DoesNotExist:
                raise Http404("No student found matching the query")
            else:
                return obj
        return None # create view

    def get_view(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        forms = {"userform": UserForm(request.POST or None, instance=self.object), guardian..., contact...} # other 5-6 forms}
        if request.POST:
            invalid_forms = [form.is_valid() for form in self.forms.values()]
            if not all(invalid_forms):
                messages.error(request,'You must fill up all the valid mandatory form fields!')
            else:
                #-- Logic to validate and save each form
        return render(request, self.template_name, forms)  

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = self.get_object()
        return self.get_view(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = self.get_object()
        return self.get_view(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Perfect, I was looking for this approach only. Thank you very much. Also I was missing `instance=self.object`.

Comment: one more quick question, Do I need to define separate 2 urls? Is there anyway I can merge them for the same `View`?

Comment: Maybe, but for code readability, I would keep both.

Comment: Ok, Thanks but now with this view. In the urls I am getting error - `AttributeError: type object 'StudentView' has no attribute 'as_view'`

Comment: Did you inherited from `View` : `class StudentView(View):` ?

Comment: Yes, I copied entire code as is and just to test did specific changes only for `UserForm`

Comment: Sorry my bad, there was already a StudentView (I was trying out earlier) Thanks for your efforts