# Disable Django Form Field only in UpdateView

Tags: django, django-forms, disable, emailfield

I have a `UserForm` in forms.py which is common between `Register` and `Edit Profile` features, its Views are also common, as 90% of the functionalities are similar in both the views.

I want to `disable` the `EMailField` from `UserForm` only in `Edit Profile` page but should be editable in `Register` page. Here is my code:

forms.py

```
class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
  password = None
  email = forms.EmailField(required=False, disabled=True)  #-- This will disable all the times
  salutation = forms.ChoiceField(choices=Choices.SALUTATIONS)
  blood_group = forms.ChoiceField(choices=Choices.BLOOD_GROUPS)

  class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ('salutation', 'blood_group', 'email', 'first_name', 'middle_name', 'last_name', 
              'gender', 'birth_date', 'profile')
```

Same Form is being rendered both the times in `register` and `edit` views. Here are my urls.py.

```
path('register/', StudentView.as_view(), name='addview'), 
path('<int:pk>/edit/', StudentView.as_view(), name='editview'),
```

in the views.py  (For detailed views.py, check the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63590880/django-createupdateview-implementation-in-the-django-template))

```
userform = UserForm(request.POST or None, instance=self.object)
```

admission.html

```
<form class="form" name="admissionForm" id="admissionForm" method="post" 
            enctype="multipart/form-data" action="{% url 'editview' form.instance.id %}"> 
 {% csrf_token %}
  <div class="pages">
     <h4 class="mt-2 mb-3">Personal Information</h4>
      {% include "student_errors.html" %}                
      {{userform|crispy}}      
      ....
      <div class="btn_container">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info float-right btn-next">Submit</button>  
      </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your update_views you can set: 
`form.fields['email'].disabled = True`